# Bootswatch - weird effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootswatch's Paper Bootstrap theme to introduce Material-like effect to my webpage in minimum effort (currently I'm using Bootstrap 3). However, I've encountered a number of weird effects - even on simple proof-of-concept site. The source follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/3/paper/bootstrap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalError">Open modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modalError">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Error text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Effects looks like following:

Hovering mouse over "X" button:

[image: Hover on "X"]

Hovering mouse over close button:

[image]

What's most weird, I cannot debug that black frame with developer tools. It looks like it simply does not exist, yet it's being displayed.

Can anyone confirm these effects too? I'm using Chrome 61.0.3163.100.
What may be the cause? How to debug these effects?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/6qPDAoe.png) in `Chromium 62.0.3202.75`

Comment: What the- ... I just upgraded Chrome to 62.0.3202 and I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Bug in Chrome's renderer?

Comment: Seems so. Just found [that](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24233). Not sure if related but [this](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/issues/686) is interesting as well.